Livewire3: programmatic update not reflecting in bound html input
I am struggling to get Livewire 3 to update my  fields when there is a programmatic change. A good example is the simple Counter provided by Caleb - if you add an input bound to the value of $count. The variable updates of course, but it is not seen in the input. Here is the code.
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Counter extends Component
{
public $count = 1;

public function increment()
{
    $this->count++;
}

public function decrement()
{
    $this->count--;
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.counter');
}
}

And here is the Blade:
<div>
    <h1>{{ $count }}</h1>

    <input type="number" wire:model.live="count" />

    <button wire:click="increment">+</button>

    <button wire:click="decrement">-</button>
</div>

Any suggestions?

code is correct, make sure you have
@livewireScripts included in your layout file, since you are not defining any specific layout to use it should be using guest.blade.php by default. which is located at resources\views\layouts\guest.blade.php

In Livewire 3, @livewireScripts is redundant so this is not helpful
